# how to get scrollwidth from the javascript in iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ibooks

I am trying to load an epub file in chapter wise into the webview. I want to know the width of the screen.

For Example:

```
if the content have one and half page text means it returns the width to be as 768
but
if the content have two full page text means it returns the width to be as 1536
```

my code is:

```
int totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth"] intValue];

"document.body.scrollWidth" returns you size of UIWebView's content.

Comment: this also returns the same way, is there any to rectify this

Comment: use this inside - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView  method you will get the correct scrollwidth of the content of webpage.

Comment: - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView{
int totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];

still i didnt get scroll width sir.

here i put inside only sir
}

Comment: how can you say that? didn't get it means what? what is the output You are getting?

Comment: i am getting total width to be 768 when the page is 1 and half size whereas in if the page is of full screen it returns as 1536...